# swt jface tableviewer get row by data

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have successfully mapped an array of objects to a table using a `TableViewer`. I used `ArrayContentProvider` and then `TableViewer.setInput` to map my array.

What I need to do now is change the background color of several rows in the table in order to visually highlight them.  Each row corresponds to an object in the array.  But I can't figure out how to obtain a reference to a row (ie, its `TableItem`) given an object of the mapped type. I can obtain an object given a row with `TableItem.getData()` but what I really want to do is get the `TableItem` given its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call protected method [`TableViewer.doFindItem`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TableViewer.html#doFindItem%28java.lang.Object%29) using reflection.

Or better, make your label provider implement [`ITableColorProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITableColorProvider.html) and the `TableViewer` will use the correct color automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just using ColumnLabelProvider as is, and didn't investigate enough about the interfaces it implements. ITableColorProvider did the trick.